# Git: How to fix pooched tracking

Tags: git

Problem:
I have confusing branch entries in my local and remote repos due to an ill-conceived tracking attempt. Can someone help me figure out how to fix or undo what I've done?

Details:
In trying to better see when things changed on the remote repo, I tried to add tracking relationships for all my branches. However, in hindsight I didn't truly understand what I had read and I made a few bad entries (that I want to get rid of but am unsure of how without making things worse).

Each branch in both my local and remote repos have duplicate (kinda/sorta) entries. For example

```
$git branch -lvv
dev                630d6fd [remotes/origin/dev]
master             a7a913c [remotes/origin/master]
origin/dev         a4df258 [master: behind 3]
origin/master      a4df258 [master: behind 3]
```

and

```
git branch -rvv
origin/dev                630d6fd
origin/master             a7a913c
origin/origin/dev         a4df258
origin/origin/master      a4df258
```

It isn't clear to me how to remove/delete/unset the "origin/origin" entries without messing things up more. I'm reading the docs and forums, but I'm not getting it.

**Edit**
... so, my uncertainty centers around "I don't know what I'm removing". In other words,

- am I just deleting a hash? That sounds pretty safe.
- OR could I possibly be deleting part of my project by `git branch -D origin/origin/master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here (well, ok, **one of** the problem**s** here :-) ) is that git is trying to be friendly and helpful and convenient, and in the process just makes a confusing situation even more confusing.

#### Safety first

First, let's note that except for `git push`, everything you do only affects your own repository.  Your `origin/whatever` entries are just *copies* of what your git saw over on `origin` the last time you did a `git push` or `git fetch`.  (Note that `git pull` is another one of those things intended for convenience; it runs `git fetch` and that's the step that actually updates the "what I, your git, saw when I last looked at the remote" entries copied to your repository.)

This means that even if we break things we're only breaking them locally until `git push`.  Not necessarily *great* but at least we're somewhat safe. :-)

#### References

Next, let's fold back the curtains and see how branch and remote-tracking branch names *actually* work.  Run this command:

```
$ git for-each-ref
```

You should see output that looks something like this:

```
...
a7a913c................................. commit refs/heads/master
a4df258................................. commit refs/heads/origin/master
...
a4df258................................. commit refs/remotes/origin/origin/master
```

(I put in `...`s to mark stuff as unknown, uninteresting, don't-care, etc here).

Look at the *full* reference names on the right: some start with `refs/heads/` and some start with `refs/remotes/` (you might even have others like `refs/tags/` and `refs/stash`).  These are *all* your references.

The ones that start with `refs/heads/` are your *branches*, and the ones that start with `refs/remotes/` are your *remote-tracking branches*.  The `git branch` command shows the first set by default (or with `-l`), and shows the second set when used with `-r`.

Note that `refs/heads/origin/master` is unambiguously a regular (local) branch named `origin/master`, and `refs/remotes/origin/master` is unambiguously a remote-tracking branch, for remote `origin`, named `master`.  However, when git helpfully (?) strips off the `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` parts, you're left with `origin/master` both times.  Sometimes git realizes that there seems to be a problem here, and strips off only `refs/`, leaving you with `remotes/origin/master`: no longer ambiguous, but still confusing.

#### What `git branch -d` (or `-D`) deletes

As with showing branches, the `git branch` front-end tries to be helpful when deleting branches too.  When used without `-r`, it will only delete a *local* branch, i.e., a reference starting with `refs/heads/`.  When used *with* `-r`, it will only delete a *remote-tracking* branch, i.e., a reference starting with `refs/remotes/`.  Hence:

```
$ git branch -D origin/master
```

deletes the *local* branch `refs/heads/origin/master`.  (With `-r` it would delete the remote-tracking branch: probably not what you want, but not that big a deal since you can restore it by fetching from the remote.)  And:

```
$ git branch -r -D origin/origin/master
```

deletes the remote-tracking branch `refs/heads/origin/origin/master` (unless git gets confused, in which case you may have to resort to using `git update-ref`, or editing `.git/packed-refs` and/or removing `.git/refs/remotes/origin/origin/master`, but the last time I saw this kind of bug was in git 1.7-something I think).

So far so good—we now know how to say *which reference is affected*—but to repeat the section header, **what does `git branch -d` actually delete?**  The answer is that two things go away immediately: the full reference name—`refs/heads/origin/master`, for instance—and also the *reflog* for that reference, if one exists.  The reflog is where git stores the previous values kept in a reference.  These are what let you use `master@{1}` or `dev@{1.week.ago}` to see which commit the reference referred-to earlier.

#### What about the commits themselves?

The commits stick around, at least for a short while.

All repository objects—commits, annotated tags, "trees" (information about which files have which names, and their execution bits), and "blobs" (file contents, minus the file names: the names are in the trees)—are stored in the repository under their SHA-1s.  That is, the hash value of the *contents* of the object is the key to retrieving the object itself from the git repository, which in the end is basically just a key/value database with some wrappers added.

The objects themselves would live forever, and eventually, stale ones would bloat up the repository, so git has a *garbage collector* (`git gc`) that finds stale, un-referenced objects and throws them out.  Git runs the garbage collector automatically as needed, after doing operations that tend to add a lot of junk and might need some collecting.  The `git branch` command is not one of these commands, even though deleting a reference could turn a lot of referenced objects into un-referenced objects.

Nonetheless, eventually something you do will run `git gc` (even if it's just you manually running `git gc`).  At this point, *truly* un-referenced objects will get tossed out.  But take a look at your original `git branch` output for a moment:

> ```
> dev                630d6fd [remotes/origin/dev]
> master             a7a913c [remotes/origin/master]
> origin/dev         a4df258 [master: behind 3]
> origin/master      a4df258 [master: behind 3]
> ```

Note that both `origin/dev` and `origin/master` refer directly to the *same* commit.  That is, they have the same associated hash value, the `a4df258` thing (truncated to 7 characters for convenience).  Taking either one out still leaves the commit referenced *directly* by the other one, which clearly protects it.

What if we take both out?  That's a bit trickier, but the answer is still in the quoted output here.  These two (local) branches are tracking local branch `master`.  The commit `master` points to is `a7a913c`, which is different; but we see `behind 3` as well, which tells us that if we start from commit `a7a913c` and work back through its parent commits, after three steps we'll come to `a4df258`.

In other words, if we draw a bit of the commit graph, and then label the commits with their IDs, we will see:

```
... <- o <- * <- o <- o <- ●   <-- master
```

The rightmost commit, which I marked as `●` (hopefully this filled-in circle works in your font) and to which `master` points directly, is `a7a913c`.  We don't know what the next one is, nor the one after that, but the one I drew as `*` is `a4df258`.

This means that commit `a4df258` remains referenced via `master`, just indirectly (three steps back).  So it won't go away.

#### Conclusion

You may safely delete the accidental branches.  The `git branch -D` command *should* just work, as long as you give it `-r` to delete the remote-tracking branches and avoid giving it `-r` to delete the regular (local) branches.  (You will need to make sure you have some other branch checked out first, such as `master` or `dev`, since `git branch` won't let you delete the branch you have checked out.)

Comment: It is worth noting that even if you do `git branch -D` and then `git gc`, the commits will not be truly deleted because, by default, the `reflog` will keep references to the deleted log for 90 days.

Comment: I'm not a big boy yet, so I'm not allowed to vote you up (although I do have my pull-ups on). But dude, that was awesome! +gajillion

Comment: @rodrigo: yes, except (alas!) deleting a ref also deletes its reflog.  But the special reflog for `HEAD` often (not always) retains the items.  The retention time is only 30 days for unreachable-from-tip references (it's a bit complicated, we expire the reflog *entries* first, *then* expire the objects)—so 30 days is a safer number to use for "how long you have to change your mind", even though 90 days applies for reachable-from-tip things.

Answer (score 0):

> It isn't clear to me how to remove/delete/unset the "origin/origin" entries
>   .. that I want to get rid of but am unsure of how without making things worse

```
# To delete a remote branch use:
git push origin --delete <branch name> 

# to delete local branch (force delete) use:
git branch -D <branch name>
```

Comment: you can also delete a remote branch using: `git push origin :branch`

Comment: will be the same result, only different syntax

Comment: yes, I know, I just find the second easier to remember :)

Comment: I guess I'm afraid that if I do `git branch -D origin/master` that it's going to delete my master branch

Comment: Only locally, if you want to delete the remote branch you need to use `push --delete`